# Check multiples hasattr in the same condition

Tags: python, hasattr

```
if hasattr(form, 'name') and hasattr(form, 'date'):
   print(form.name) #'Some name' - True
   print(form.date) #none - False
```

This condition validates as True even if the `hasattr(form, 'date')` is false.

What is the correct way to validate multiples `hasattr?`

Comment: Note that `hasattr` checks purely for existence. If it exists but is falsy it's still true. You may want a form of `getattr` instead - but also double check you don't mean `form.name` instead of just `name`...

Answer (score 19):

You can use `all`

```
if all(hasattr(form, attr) for attr in ["name", "date"])
```

Comment: That's pretty handy: any(hasattr(form, attr) for attr in ["name", "date"])

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one value to check if it is a truthy attribute of an object, you can do like this

```
if all(getattr(form, attrib) for attrib in ["name", "date"]):
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking is probably not `hasattr`, but `getattr`.

```
if getattr(form, 'name') and getattr(form, 'date'):
```

As `hasattr` will check if `form` has the attribute `name`. It will check if `form.name` exists, not getting the value of `form.name`. And `getattr` is there for that!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Even if the *value* of the attribute is `False`, it still *has* the attribute which is why it is not failing (as you are expecting it to).

`hasattr` will only check if the attribute exists, not what its value is. You need `getattr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try use getattr:

```
if getattr(form, 'name', None) and getattr(form, 'date', None):
    print(name)
    print(date)
```

getattr(form, 'name', None) - this None is default value, if not field

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is fine. Your use of the variables below probably isn't -- I think you mean to use `form.name`  and `form.date`.

If you want to check whether they exist *and* that their value isn't None, try:

```
if getattr(form, 'name') is not None and getattr(form, 'date') is not None:
    print(form.name)
    print(form.date)
```